# How to retrieve values in Firebase database and insert them into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my database structure (in red my comments):

[image]

The purpose is to show on a simple web page photos of a trip. I am trying to retrieve the value "photourl" in this database for each photo of a trip.

Here is my html code:

```
  <div class="main">

      <div class="spot">

        <img id="image" height="400" width="400"/>

      </div>

  </div>

    <p><script>document.write(userid);</script></p>
    <p><script>document.write(tripid);</script></p>
    <p><script>document.write(photourl);</script></p>
```

The last 3 lines are just here to show whether the variables have any value (and when I try my html code, it doesn't show any).

And my javascript code:

```
//Get User ID and Trip ID in URL

function GetURLParameter(sParam)
{
var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
{
    var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
    if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
    {
        return sParameterName[1];
    }
}
}
   var userid = GetURLParameter('userid');
   var tripid = GetURLParameter('tripid');

//Get image from database

var database = firebase.database();
return firebase.database().ref('/photos/' + userid + 'trips' + 
tripid).once('photourl').then(function(insert) 
{
document.getElementsById('image').src = photourl;  
});
```

My URL will be something like this then: https://travelertest-e316f.firebaseapp.com/?userid=11K47L3qgUOateC4LGSE29Un2W53&tripid=-Kiv3kukHYLMVefSGPqZ

I don't know how to make it work so that it retrieves all "photourl" values no matter how many photos there are in a trip. And I don't know how to display them on a simple html page so that the page shows as many photos as in the trip.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the trip object and get the photourls in an array:

```
// add a return statement here if you'll use it as a function
database.ref(`photos/${userId}/trips/${tripId}`).once('value') // will return you all the photo objects inside the `tripId`
.then(photosSnap => {
    const photosObj = photosSnap.val();
    const photosUrl = Object.keys(photosObj).map(key => photosObj[key].photourl);
    // then you can return the array or use it here;
    console.log(photosUrl); // will be an array of all the photourls
}).catch(err => alert(err));
```